# How can we show list of data Categories wise list horizontal in react- native

Tags: listview, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-flatlist

I am new in react-native  i want need horizontal list based on Categories wise

I attached Image , i don't know how can i write the code means to design this component.

I have Different categories like Fashion, Watches, Bags, Shirts, Trousers, Cloths, Brands like different categories wise show to horizontal list items inside.

I didn't mentioned the code , because i don't know how can i start this initially.

if i am clicking see all button then show list of grid collection another screen / model

Please give me sample or suggestion

This is my Required Image:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You seem like you already know about FlatLists so I don't know what you mean when you say you don't know where to start...
Nevertheless:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { View, Text, FlatList } from 'react-native'

export default class TempScreen extends React.Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      exampleData: [
        {name: 'Watch', price: '100'},
        {name: 'Big Watch', price: '888'},
        {name: 'Expensive Watch', price: '999999'},
        {name: 'Donald Trump', price: '-1'},
      ]
    }
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <View>
        <Text style = {{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>Fashion</Text>
        <FlatList 
          horizontal
          data = {this.state.exampleData}
          renderItem = {({item}) => 
            <View style = {{padding: 10}}>
              <View style = {{backgroundColor: 'white', borderWidth: 1, borderColor: '#626262', height: 50, width: 50}}/>
              <Text>{item.name}</Text>
              <Text>{item.price}</Text>
            </View>}
          />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Please tell me if it works

Comment: Hi if i want more display like what you mentioned , because i have  more Categories.

you give only one Categories but i have more how can i display more Categories

Comment: You can try using a `SectionList`

Comment: I tried Section List but it's not working horizontal

Comment: if you don't mine could you give me any sample

Comment: what do you mean it's not working horizontally? just add `horizontal = { true }`

Comment: i mean u said aobut horizontal it's not working in Section List

Comment: if you dont mind could you give me sample format file

Comment: Or if you want to have titles above every horizontal list you can write your own component using a flatlist

Comment: i have more components it depends up on backend some times 3 some times 100 what should i do

Comment: is it possible like sample design??

Answer (score 0):

Guess what, to get a horizontal list is really easy! Just add the horizontal attribute to our list.

```
<FlatList
        horizontal
        data={this.state.data}
       .
       .
       .
       //whatever props you want to pass
      />
    );
  }
}
```